# "Updating" all state in redux app properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, assign, reducers

I've met some trouble assigning a new object in the reducer of my app. My state contains 2 arrays :

```
{
    elements: [],
    constraints: []
}
```

Those elements are handled by 2 reducers :

```
elementsReducer
constraintsReducer
```

and combined like this:

```
let reducer = combineReducers({
    elements: elementsReducer,
    constraints: constraintsReducer
});

export default reducer
```

So, basically, an action is triggered, and my reducer is supposed to update all the state.elements array. I've tried several things and I can't update the whole elements array, only - in the best case - the first element.

My first idea was to do:

```
        return  Object.assign({}, state, {
            elements: state.map((e) => {
                return Object.assign({}, e, {
                    text: action.data[e.id][e.text]
                })
            })
        });
```

action.data is an array containing a different text for each element. Basically, all I was to do is, on a special action, updating all the element array. But this syntax does not work as it creates a new array INSIDE the array "elements" of the store. It does not replace it. If I let this, the store becomes:

```
{
    elements: [
         elements: [...]
    ],
    constraints: [...]
}
```

When I access the state in my reducer elementsReducer, it's only the "element" array and not the full state. After this issue, I've tried to do the following:

```
return state.map(function(e) {
    return assign({}, e, {
          text: action.data[e.id][e.text]
   });
});
```

Now, I worked, but the ONLY element mapped is the first one. The other elements are simply not updating.

Do you have any idea to solve the issue?

Thanks everyone :)
Xelys

EDIT :

```
// code of elementsReducer
var assign = require('object-assign');

export default function elementsReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_ELEMENT':
            return [...state,
                {
                    name: action.name,
                    id: action.id,
                    committed: false,
                    text: action.text
                }
            ]
        case 'COMMIT_ELEMENT':
            console.log('commit action')
            return state.map(function(e) {
                return e.id === action.id ?
                assign({}, e, {committed: true}) :
                e
            });
        case 'SAVE_DATA':
            return state.map((e) => {
                return Object.assign({}, e, {
                    text: action.data[e.id][e.text]
                });
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the code for `elementsReducer`?

Comment: sure, here it comes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I assumed your data structure is like below:

```
// state.element
stateElement = [
    { id:1, text: '1t' },
    { id:2, text: '2t' }
];

// Your action result
action = {
    data: {
        1: { text: 'new 1t' },
        2: { text: 'new 2t' }
    }
}

// Your new state.element
newData = data.map(function(e) {
    return Object.assign({}, e, {
          text: action.data[e.id].text
   });
});
```

Comment: Can you check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477055/how-can-i-dispatch-function-in-redux

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers.

@Ali Sepehri.Kh, yeah, my data structure is very similar. Actually, it's a little bit more complex, but I've simplified it to be more understable.

However, I figured out to solve the issue. I feel quite ashamed of creating a post on stackoverflow, because the error had nothing to do with redux.

The mapping function I've used was totally working. The issue was located is the action data. The function which created the action.data array was returning an array empty after the first element. I thought the issue was coming from the map() as it was for me the "most difficult" part of the fonction.

However, I've made a stupid mistake on the fonction creating the array of the action. I have misplaced a "return" inside a for loop, which explain that all the elements after the first one were empty.

Sorry for your time guys, and thanks for the help :).